# The result is incorrect html element is get json in ionic 2

Tags: html, json, ionic-framework, element

I used get json in ionic.

```
$http.get($scope.webServiceUrl+"example.php")
  .then(function(response){
    $rootScope.lists = response.data;
  });
```

#### I wrote the webservice with php

```
echo json_encode($data,JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

#### return json data and print page

```
text: "<h1>enes</h1>"
```

Json `[{"id":"0","text":"<h1>enes</h1>"}]`

[jsonviewer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAwVY.png)

#### Result when I print to the page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMD8R.png)

Does not accept is html element. How can i solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive if you are sure it's safe and can be rendered as unencoded HTML.

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```